# Ember changedAttributes() not show boolean change

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've been trying to store a list of changes to a model into another model before saving it, so that I can recall the changes to undo previous changes. This is the code that I'm using:

```
var changes = item.changedAttributes();
var newUndo = this.store.createRecord('undo', {
  item_id: item.get('id'),
  changes: changes
});
```

And my checkbox is a typical one:

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=checked class="checkbox"}}
```

I have a component for the checkbox that sends a save action when checked changes, and the controller's save method is calling the code above when before saving the record:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  checked: false,
  model: null,
  watchChecked: function () {
    this.sendAction('save', this.get('model'))
  }.observes('checked')
});
```

**And the undo model**

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.Model.extend({
  item_id: DS.attr('number'),
  changes: DS.attr('string')
});
```

This works well for string attributes, but with boolean checkboxes, it's not acting as expected. This is what I'm seeing:

Page load, unchecked item is checked:

```
changes: {}
```

Then unchecked:

```
changes: {print_copy_sent: true,true}
```

Then checked again:

```
changes: {print_copy_sent: false,false}
```

Comment: could you put this in a [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com)?

Comment: Your `changes` attribute on the model you're creating seems a little odd. Would you mind posting the definition for your `undo` model?

Comment: GJK -- I've added. I struck me as a little odd as well, but it does seem to be working, at least so far – which is mainly on string-oriented fields.

Comment: It occurred to me that perhaps I could be offloading this to Rails to some extent since the model is versioned within Rails, I could generate the undo within Ember after saving, and simply store the revision number, rather than the changed attributes, and then just figure out how to make Ember rollback the record to the specified revision from a separate Rails API endpoint.